# Pasting artwork from Illustrator into Photoshop causes edges

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

[image: What's going on here]

This may have been asked, but I can't find any solution to this other than putting pixels behind them in PS.

Answer (score 2):

Making sure "anti-aliasing" is turned off before confirming the paste fixed it!

Comment: The better solution may be to keep anti-aliasing and duplicate the imported object's layer twice. Ideally though, you'd overlap the objects in illustrator before importing.